# Choosing Audio Stream While Converting Via FFmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-conversion, audio-streaming

I`ve got a .mkv file with two audio streams. But when I intent to convert it to a .mp4, the ffmpeg only chooses the first audio stream.
How can I make ffmpeg to uses second one?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235376/how-do-i-add-vtt-subtitles-to-a-mp4-video-to-view-on-an-iphone-ios, https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/subtitle_options. That is for subtitles but it gives examples. Try

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy output.mp4
```

Use `-map 0:a:1` if only the 2nd audio stream is required. (Or maybe it is `-map 1:a`.)

Comment: It's not `-map 1:a`. There's only one input file.